# Factorization algorithm

Tags: algorithm-design, factoring

I want to show that if we can compute order of element a mod n for all a and n with an efficient algorithm then there is an efficient algorithm for factoring numbers
Can some one give me solution?
Thanks

Comment: So what do you expect from us? Giving you such an algorithm? Explaining you the core idea behind that? Giving you hints towards finding the algorithm yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking for is a generalization of [the problem of recovering $p,q$ given $e,d,N$ in RSA,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5747013/4733946) which is solveable in polynomial time. You're also basically asking for the [classical part of Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm#Classical_part).

---

So, assume we know the order of $a$ modulo the composite to-factor $N$ and call it $k$. By definition we *know*:
$$a^k\equiv 1\pmod N$$

Thus we know that $x=a^{k/m}\bmod N$ ($m$ being a power of 2 such that $k/m$ is an integer) is a square-root of unity $\bmod N$ of which we know there are $2^l$ if $N$ has $l$ distinct, odd prime factors (this can be seen by using [the CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) and powers of two are trivial to factor out). We also know that all of these square roots $x$ satisfy all of the equations $x\equiv\pm1\pmod{p_i}$ (with one particular, independent pick for the sign for each factor) where $p_i$ are the prime factors of $N$.

$$f_1=\gcd(x-1,N)f_2=N/f_1$$

will reveal you a new (non-trivial) factor iff $x\not\equiv\pm1\pmod N$. At this point you can apply this factoring algorithm recursively on $f_1$ and $f_2$ separately which will eventually yield you [primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) and prime-powers (which are [perfect-powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power#Detecting_perfect_powers)) exclusively for which you can test in polynomial time.

---

As for why $\gcd(x-1,N)>1:$ Note how you get $x\equiv\pm1\pmod N$ iff $x\equiv\pm1\pmod{p_i}$ for all $p_i$ (all the signs are the same here for all factors). If not, there's one (not neccessarily prime) factor $f_1$ of $N$ for which $x\equiv1\pmod{f_1}$ which means that $x-1$ *must* be a multiple of $f_1$ and thus $\gcd(x-1,N)$ will recover $f_1$. This doesn't work if $f_1=1$ which would be the case if all the signs in the equations for the prime factors would be $-1$. This also doesn't work if all the signs are positive, because then you have $x=N-1\equiv-1\pmod N$ and $N$ and $N-2$ cannot possibly have any non-trivial factors in common ($>2$ at least), because $\gcd(N,N-2)=\gcd(2,N-2)$ which can tell you no more than whether your $N$ is even.

---

So what happens if $k$ is odd? In this case you just got unlucky and pick a new (random) $a$ until you hit an even $k$. Note that if $N>2$, there [must](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/266523/262906) exist such a $k$, because $\varphi(N)$ ($\varphi(n)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)) is the order of $\mathbb Z^*_N$ and it *must* be even because you can construct $\varphi(n):=\begin{cases}\varphi(l)\cdot\varphi(m)&\text{for }n=lm,\gcd(l,m)=1\\p^{k-1}(p-1)&\text{for }n=p^k,p\in\mathbb P,k\geq1\end{cases}$ and every $n\neq2$ will either contain $p-1$ for some odd prime, which is even again or $2^1$ (if $4|n$) which also makes this even.

Also note that the chances of "hitting" an $a$ with odd order randomly [are (at least) bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059778/262906) $\Pr[2\not\mid k]\leq \frac{1}{2^{\omega(N)}}$ where $\omega(N)$ [is the number of distinct primes diving $N$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#.CF.89.28n.29_.E2.80.93_distinct_prime_divisors) which means the chances of hitting are very good.

Comment: Your solution is really beautiful. But what about the case that k being odd?

Comment: @user3447371 TL;DR: Pick a new one. I've added a paragraph explaining why there must exist a $a$ such that $k$ is even. I've also added treatment why $k$ will be even for random $a$ with solid probability